# How can I fix the "Could not delete temporary file"?

Tags: 7, files, cron

I'm getting below error when run cron:

> **The specified file could not be deleted, because it is not a valid URI. More information is available in the system log**.

Due to TMP files, my site will be crashed, again we will restored site and unable to clean **TMP** files in my live site.

Answer (score 1):

Change to another tmp folder destination? Configuration -> file system

I not sure will this help you.

Comment: Thnks for your quick replay @ peifa before i have tried in place of "/tmp" changed another name "/tmp2" etc no use and just i have deleted tmp file from "file_managed" table error gone away but already set cron every 1 hour after run cron tmp files must delete but in my case not work so i'm trying some custom module for against cron for deleting tmp files using hook_cron().